# How can I deploy my custom dhcp server on docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dhcp

So I code my own custom dhcp server for specific job and I want to deploy it using docker. I need to expose it on port 67/udp and use network_mode host. I tried configuring my docker-compose like this.

```
version: '3'

services:
  dhcp:
    container_name: custom_dhcp_server
    image: registry.patty.com/custom_dhcp_server:latest
    restart: always
    command: python3 -u src/dhcp_server.py
    ports: 
      - "67:67/udp"
    network_mode: "host"
```

but I just found that I can't expose port with network_mode host. So how can I deploy it using docker.

Comment: Non admin/root users can't opened ports below 1024.

Comment: @LMC But if you're running Docker, you're root.

Comment: Docker service at OS level is run by root but docker instances should be run by a non-privileged user as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I just found that I can't expose port with network_mode host.

While that's true, it's because it's unnecessary. When you're running in the host network namespace, you don't need to use port mapping because whatever port you listen on *is* a host port.  As long as your custom DHCP server is listening for UDP traffic on port 67, you're all set.

If things don't appear to be working, there are a number of diagnostic steps you can try.

- What happens if you run a non-custom dhcp server? [dnsmasq](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) is good for this because it's relatively simple to configure.
- Add debugging code to your custom dhcp server. Is it receiving any requests?
- Check your firewall; any chance you're blocking the dhcp requests?

Etc.